# I can ping a Windows XP PC with the firewall off but I can't when the firewall is on. Why?

Tags: windows-xp, ping, windows-firewall

For the `ping` command, I have read (e.g. try this [link](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Which_port_is_used_by_Ping_command)), there's no port required. Yet I have a PC on my network which I cannot ping. Strangely, I can connect to using `Remote Desktop`.

However, I am able to ping it (as well as connect to it with `RDP`) when I turn off the firewall. How should I configure the firewall so that I can ping the machine even with the firewall on? I tried looking it up (the `ping` command i.e.) in the list of firewall exceptions but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Update: I can add `ping.exe` from the `system32` folder but that process is on the machine. I want the firewall to allow access to the said PC when I am trying to ping it from the outside.

Answer (score 3):

Ping uses ICMP not TCP so it is not like a normal program when opening the firewall settings.

To enable ICMP Ping packets open the Windows Firewall configuration icon in Control Panel and go to the `Advanced` tab and click the ICMP settings button

[image]

From there check the box for `Allow incoming echo request`, that is the message type that represents ping.

[image]

[IMHO blocking ICMP packets is generally not a good idea for your network health](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22711/is-it-a-bad-idea-for-a-firewall-to-block-icmp) and I would recommend checking all of the boxes to allow all types of ICMP packets unless you have a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, ping doesn't use a port.  It also doesn't use TCP or IP.  It uses a protocol called ICMP.  If you set up an exception, that's the protocol to use.